# Laravel combine multiple scope

Tags: laravel, scope

I have a `posts` table and every post can have 0, 1 or more rows into `channels` (table `channels` with `post_id` in it).

The `posts` table also has a a `privacy` field set to 0, 1 or 2.

I want to list specific posts so I defined scopes inside the `Post` model:

```
    public function scopeNonPrivate($builder)
    {
        return $builder->where(function ($q) {
            $q->where('post_privacy', '!=', Post::PRIVACY_ME);
            $q->where('user_id', '!=', auth()->id());
        })->orWhere(function ($q) {
            $q->where('post_privacy', '=', Post::PRIVACY_ME);
            $q->where('user_id', '=', auth()->id());
        });
    }

    public function scopeNonZero(Builder $builder)
    {
        return $builder->whereHas('channels', function ($query) {
            $query->where('channel_id', '!=', 0);
        })->orWhereDoesntHave('channels');
    }

    public function scopeFromFriends(Builder $builder, $friends)
    {
        return $builder->whereIn('user_id', $friends);
    }
```

I want to combine these scopes to that I can find all post `fromFriends`, which have a channel different from 0 **or** which do NOT have a channel, and with the `privacyOnlyFriends`.

When I combine these the result is not correct, this is what I do:

```
$post = Channel::find(1)
    ->posts()
    ->fromFriends([$friends->pluck('user_id'), $friends->pluck('friend_id')])
    ->nonZero()
    ->nonPrivate();
```

I defined in `App\Channel`:

```
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'post_channels', 'channel_id', 'post_id');
    }
```

And I defined in `App\Post`:

```
    public function channels()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Channel::class, 'post_channels', 'post_id', 'channel_id');
    }
```

Is there a way to keep data from the different scopes and merged together so that for example `fromFriends()` does not override `nonPrivate()` but they are merged?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine multiple scopes, below is an example from my class:

```
public function scopeGetCommentsOn($queryBuilder, $table, $tableIdentifier)
{
    return $queryBuilder->where('table_name', $table)
        ->where('table_identifier', $tableIdentifier);
}

public function scopeCommentsOnShipments($queryBuilder, $tableIdentifier)
{
    return $queryBuilder->getCommentsOn('shipments', $tableIdentifier);
}
```

In the above example, I am using scope `getCommentsOn` in `commentsOnShipments` scope.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Ok but that is not whet I need as I may need to combine many of them in certain controllers and less in others